# Same record returns multiple times based on deptno

Tags: sql

I have a **EMP** table like below

```
Eid   Ename  Deptno
1     xyz    3
2     abc    5
```

If I select eid=1 it should display deptno =3 times. I f i select eid=2 it should display deptno=5.like below.

```
1  xyz  3
1  xyz  3
1  xyz  3
```

So please do help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: presuming you have a backend programming language (maybe a large leap here...) this is probably better suited to be dealt with there by simply looping the number of times required.

Comment: what rdbms? SQL Server, MySQL, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a recursive cte

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/PJPH48805)**

```
;with cte
as
(select eid, ename, deptno, deptno AS counter from emp
union all
select cte.eid, cte.ename, deptno, cte.counter - 1
from cte
where cte.counter - 1 > 0
)

select eid, ename, deptno from cte
ORDER BY cte.eid
```